# How do you generate sub-components in Angular 6

Tags: angular6

How are components under **layout** in this project https://github.com/start-angular/SB-Admin-BS4-Angular-6 generated?. Is there angular CLI command for generating subcomponents NOT nested components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The components in the link above are child routes of the layout component.
The routing is described in layout-routing.module.ts
For example

```
{ path: 'charts', loadChildren: './charts/charts.module#ChartsModule' },
```

defines a child route for charts path.
these components will be placed in the place of *router-outlet*

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-sidebar (collapsedEvent)="receiveCollapsed($event)"></app-sidebar>
<section class="main-container" [ngClass]="{collapsed: collapedSideBar}">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
 </section>
```

*note also that layout has also subcomponents like app-header*

these components are like any other angular component so you can generate using ng component schematics (i.e. ng g c).
For the scenario above the sequence to create the chart component (given the specific layout module and routing)

```
 ng g m layout/chart  --routing  // create chart module inside layout module

 ng g c layout/chart   // create chart component inside chart module
```

after that, you have to set the routing in charts-routing.module.ts and you are good to go

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I followed the above steps but the URL redirects like so `http://localhost:4200/test/dashboard`. **dashboard** is added at end. How do I correct this?

Comment: Thanks, got it working I had forgotten `--routing` in the module command